# Get PDF images in an array using PDFIUM to edit them

Tags: c++, algorithm, image, pdf, pdfium

I am trying to write down a method to get all PDF images from a `FPDF_DOCUMENT` object to perform actions on them and return back the`FPDF_DOCUMENT` with the images replaced.

It should be like this:

1. For each (get image objects) for input `FPDF_DOCUMENT document`
2. DO something to each.
3. Replace the original objects back to the `FPDF_DOCUMENT`
4. Return the `FPDF_DOCUMENT`

Does that make sense?

I am lost in PDFium source as there are no documentation. Pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the following methods/steps:

- Open document with `FPDF_LoadDocument` or equivalent
- Call `FPDF_GetPageCount` on the document to get the amount of pages
- Loop through the pages

  - Call `FPDF_LoadPage` for every page there is
  - Call `FPDFPage_CountObjects` to get the amount of objects
  - Loop through all the objects

    - Call `FPDFPage_GetObject` on every object
    - Call `FPDFPageObj_GetType` on every loaded object
    - Check if the page object is of type `FPDF_PAGEOBJ_IMAGE`, then continue, else skip
    - Do your magic (probably `FPDFImageObj_GetBitmap` / `FPDFImageObj_SetBitmap`?)
  - Possibly you have to call `FPDFPage_GenerateContent` to make sure the internal page is updated with the changes
  - Call `FPDF_ClosePage` to close the page
- Call `FPDF_SaveAsCopy` to save the new PDF
- Call `FPDF_CloseDocument` to close the original document.